# Flickr photos.getSizes returning undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, flickr

So I'm trying to return the URL from a set of photos (using the getInterestingList) I am able to return them, but whenever I try narrow down the results and only return the source it just returns undefined in the console.

This is my code:

```
function getInteresting() {

    var interestingStr = 'https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.interestingness.getList&' + APIkey + '&per_page=20&format=json&nojsoncallback=1';

    $.get(interestingStr, function (data) {


        fetchLink(data);
    });
}

function fetchLink(data) {

    for (var i = 0; i < data.photos.photo.length; i++) {
        //console.log(data.photos.photo[i].id);
        var photoObject = data.photos.photo[i];
        var getSizesStr = 'https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.getSizes&' + APIkey + '&photo_id=' + data.photos.photo[i].id + '&format=json&nojsoncallback=1';

        $.get(getSizesStr, function (data) {
            console.log(data.sizes.size.source); /**This is where i'm printing the result. Whenever I put in .source it returns undefined, but whenever I leave it as sizes.size it returns correctly**

        });
    }
```

What happens when I leave it as sizes.size:

[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]0: Objectheight: 75label: "Square"media: "photo"source: "https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3900/15073487900_0b89b0e136_s.jpg"url: "https://www.flickr.com/photos/janleonardo/15073487900/sizes/sq/"width: 75

when I try get the source: (desired result:
undefined

Any Ideas? Thanks

edit: I'm using REst / JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed:

What I did was add another for loop inside my GET call to the getSizes api,

```
$.get(getSizesStr, function (data) {
            for (var x = 0; x < data.sizes.size.length; x++) {
                console.log(data.sizes.size[x].source);
```

and it worked.